# ssh incorrect password issue bridge

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bridge

we have setup multiple vm's on  the bridge in ubuntu.This bridge  assign ip's manually and ip belongs to the host network.We have setup password authentication for host authentication.

I can ssh into newly logged in vm from host machine but i can't log in to these m/c manually outside the host vm,example from another node after 1st attempt.
i get ssh key changed message subsequently  and  somehow ssh key get changed . i can't login after it with incorrect password error..
Does anybody has any pointers?

Update:
I just recognize that if i run ssh keyscan ,i see it is showing different version of ssh other than present on host or client machine.

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0-hpn14v15 FreeBSD-openssh-portable-8.0.p1,1
```

instead of installed

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.
```

Do we know what can cause it or how to force server to use correct ssh version?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly what ssh commands you are running and exactly what error messages you're getting. Don't paraphrase error messages. It may be helpful to run ssh with the "-v" option to print debugging info, then include the debugging info in your question.

Comment: We gave got 3 vm's .i can access 1 vm consistently and if i run keyscan it is still using SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0 ,while it is changed to SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0-hpn14v15 FreeBSD-openssh-portable-8.0.p1,1 for other two?

Comment: ok thanks!...i can try to find it..But my question is why ssh authentication works initially and then suddenly i got host key changed method and this version of ssh appears . Do we have way to force ssh to use particular version?

Comment: At a guess you've already assigned the IP to a FreeBSD box

Comment: it looks like network was advertising wrong ip causing this issue